# Converting JSP Pages to servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

We also have HTML tags in JSP pages so while executing the jsp, it get converted into Servlet. So my question is what happened to HTML tags or where we can find HTML tags in servlet ?

Comment: You can use `out.println()`.

Comment: If I have created some headline with some logic in jsp page while running the page what will happen to html tags....i know logic will get converted into servlet service methos but what about to html tags

Comment: Use `JSTL` pass the varieble,object through `response` from servlets then you will be able to access it from `JSP` files.

Comment: This article could help you https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-for-converting-JSP-to-Servlet

Answer (score 1):

Every JSP page identified by ".jsp" and  converted into Servlet by JSP Engine.Some Example are:-

File:-dashboardApp.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="appResources/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<!-- jquery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="appResources/jquery/jquery.min_3.3.1.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="dashboardApp">

<!-- ${userId}  ${userName} -->
<input type="hidden"  id="userId" name="userId" value="${userId}"  />
<input type="hidden"   id="userName" name="userName" value="${userName}" />
</body>
</html>
```

File:-dashboardApp_jsp.java(same file created by appending file-name+"_jsp.java")

All the html code inside .jsp goes into service method of servlet.Example for above .jsp file

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
 JspWriter out = out = pageContext.getOut();

  out.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n");
  out.write("<html>\r\n");
  out.write("<head>\r\n");
  out.write(" <title>Dashboard App</title>\r\n");
  out.write(" <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n");
  out.write(" <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n");
  out.write(" <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"appResources/images/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" />\r\n");
  out.write(" \r\n");
  out.write("              <!-- jquery library -->\r\n");
  out.write("   <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"appResources/jquery/jquery.min_3.3.1.js\"></script>  \r\n");
  out.write("<body ng-app=\"dashboardApp\">\r\n");
  out.write("   <input type=\"hidden\"  id=\"userId\" name=\"userId\" value=\"");
  out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${userId}", java.lang.String.class, (PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null, false));
  out.write("\"  />\r\n");
  out.write("   <input type=\"hidden\"   id=\"userName\" name=\"userName\" value=\"");
  out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${userName}", java.lang.String.class, (PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null, false));
  out.write("\" />  \r\n");
  out.write("</body>\r\n");
  out.write("</html>");
  }
```

JSP engine convert .jsp file into servlet (.java) and .class file.

Here you can find .class servlet .java (Tomcat Server).
/DashboardApp/target/tomcat/work/localEngine/localhost/DashboardApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/view/dashboardApp_jsp.java

Comment: Nice ! it helps me